# Storing 3d shapes in sql server using geometry data type and WKT

Tags: sql-server-2008, 3d, geometry, wkt

I'm looking at the geometry data type in Sql Server 2008 and it looks interesting but the documentation does not seem that good.  Would I be able to store cones, cylinders and spheres in the WKT format?  These features traditionally have a radius and not hundreds of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge your are going to have to use an external application to render your shape as a large number of points. See [this blog](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/01/09/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial---How-to-create-a-circle-.aspx) for a technique for rendering circles.

One possibility to consider is a CLR proc to render the shapes you need and a view with indexes. I don't know how well that will perform, but it just might work.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It seems the geometry type isn't what I am looking for, as I don't want to store it approximated as hundreds of points.  If I am to use it, I will probably just use geometry to store the central point and have radius as a separate field.

Comment: Accepting because the blog post showed me the data type was not for me.

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the late reply. You could always write your own ***User-Defined-Type*** called **Circle**, with two properties namely **Centroid** and **Radius**.

Inside the newly formed UDT, create a method that takes the properties Centroid (*Point3D*), and Radius (*Double*). After this, create a method that uses both **SqlGeometry** and **SqlGeometryBuilder** to build the newly formed object.

First, create a **Point** instance of *Geometry*. Inherit the Centroid values from the class object, then, create another *Geometry* **Polygon** that's derived from the *Point* object, and **STBuffer**(*Radius*) it.

Below is my example: (written in 30min)

```
public SqlGeometry ToSQLGeometry()
    {
        int srid = this.SRID; // i.e. 4326

        SqlGeometry geom = new SqlGeometry();
        SqlGeometryBuilder gb = new SqlGeometryBuilder();
        OpenGisGeometryType pt = OpenGisGeometryType.Point;

        gb.SetSrid(srid);

        gb.BeginGeometry(pt);
        gb.BeginFigure(this.Centroid.X, this.Centroid.Y, this.Centroid.Z, this.Centroid.M);
        gb.EndFigure();
        gb.EndGeometry();

        geom = gb.ConstructedGeometry;
        geom = geom.MakeValid(); // Optional for Point data

        SqlGeometry geomCircle = new SqlGeometry();
        geomCircle = geom.STBuffer(this.Radius);

        return geomCircle;
    }
```

When you've done this in VS2010 by using the CLR project type, you can deploy it to your database.

In SQL, you can call the object as such:: **Parse(X Y Z M,R)**

```
declare @c Circle
set @c = Circle::Parse('5 6 7 8,2')
select 'Circle', @c.ToString(), @c.ToSQLGeometry()
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a quick look around and found this MSDN page on [Spatial Samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2008/11/01/sql-2008-spatial-samples-part-2-of-n-background-on-spatial-types-well-known-text-wkt.aspx). It covers all the Methods to enter data in WKT, WKB & XML(GML) as well as functions to view the in Human Readable form. It also covers MakeValid, STIsValid & STSrid.

There looks to be a fair few SQL examples that you may find useful